# Remove Duplicates from List of String

Tags: java

I have the following List of String:

```
{ 
    "Name1,Name2",
    "Name2,Name1",
    "Name3,Name4",
    "Name4,Name3"
}
```

Without using any Java/C/Python/C++/C# library, I want to remove the duplicates in a way that, it prints:

```
Name1,Name2
Name3,Name4
```

One way to remove duplicates would be this:

```
private static boolean checkIfEquals(String str, String str1) {
        HashSet<String> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(",")));
        HashSet<String> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str1.split(",")));
        return set1.equals(set2);
    }
```

Comment: Why does the provided method not work?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing to me. Is "Name1, Name2" a single element, or 2 seperate elements "Name1", "Name2" etc.. ?

Comment: @OyaCanlı from the rest of the question it is quite clear the OP is asking about treating each line as an unordered set of strings, and what he wants is to get the list of unique sets of strings.

Comment: @jbk That is what I guessed from the proposed solution, but there should be " " around couple of strings to make it clear, like "Name1, Name2", "Name2, Name1" etc. We shouldn't be trying to guess what the author meant, it would be better if it is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your same approach, assuming your list of strings is in a variable `List<String> strings`:

```
List<String> unique = 
 strings.stream()
        .map(str -> new LinkedHashSet<>(Arrays.asList(str.split(","))))
        .distinct()
        .map(set -> set.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(",")))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Deadpool why what's the problem you found?

Answer (score 0):

using c++

```
int main(){
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    string list[4]={
                    "Name1,Name2",
                    "Name2,Name1",
                    "Name3,Name4",
                    "Name4,Name3"
                    };

    map<string,bool>exist;
    vector<string>flist;

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        string s=list[i];
        sort(s.begin(),s.end());

        if(exist[s])continue;

        exist[s]=true;
        flist.push_back(list[i]);
    }                

    for(auto item :flist)cout<<item<<"\n";
}
```